# IDE for developing iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, ide, development-environment

I am starting using iPad. I don't have any other mac machine like MacBook etc where I can install Xcode.

Could you guys please advise me if I am able to code some even simple apps with use only iPad? Is there any IDE available on this device? What it's name?

For example I need to prepare app connecting by Bluetooth with some devices and reading some informations from those ones and then displaying informations in my app.

I will appreciate all tips as long as I am new apple user.

Regards,
Hubert

Comment: you could emulate a Mac on some other computer, with virtual box or similar. or you search for hackintosh. But beware: Apples EULAs say that you are only allowed to run macOS on Mac hardware. but technically that would be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need a Mac. You can develop something called Playgrounds on your iPad but that's it.

Comment: Playgrounds are intended for learning and experimenting, and only have limited ability to interact with the lower level frameworks. I doubt seriously you could write a Playground that does BLE.